# How do I get links of files in a directory one by one to use them?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<div class="video" data-tags="Awesome" data-video-url="LINK OF FIRST VIDEO FILE IN THE DIRECTORY /VIDEOS WITH A PREVIEW IMAGE">

<div class="video" data-tags="Awesome" data-video-url="LINK OF SECOND VIDEO FILE IN THE DIRECTORY /VIDEOS WITH A PREVIEW IMAGE">
```

As the above code shows, I need something that can break files in a director and generate links for the items one by one.

How can I do that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php#88459

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function dirToArray($dir) {
   $result = array();
   $cdir = scandir($dir);
   foreach ($cdir as $key => $value)
   {
      if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))
      {
         if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value))
         {
            $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
         }
         else
         {
            $result[] = $value;
         }
      }
   }

   return $result;
}

$files = dirToArray("/home/user/folder")
foreach ($files as $file) {
   echo "<div class='video' data-tags='Awesome' data-video-url='$file'>";
}
?>
```